# How Get Remove this React-minification even though I set node_env to production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am new to React js.I am still getting this Even though I set My Node env to production in my gulp file.How to Remove this console logs.
[image]

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var through2 =require('through2');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');



gulp.task('browserify',function () {
   gulp.src('./src/changenametogulpwhenditingmain.js')
       .pipe(plumber())
       .pipe(through2.obj(function (file,enc,next) {
          browserify(file.path,{'debug':true})
              .transform('reactify')
              .bundle(function (err,res) {
                 file.contents = res
                 next(null,file);
});
}))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
});
gulp.task('apply-prod-environment', function() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
});

gulp.task('default',['apply-prod-environment','browserify']);


gulp.task('watch',function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.*',['default']);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried following the link?

Comment: yes i've tried that.That's the reason I changed to production Mode But Still Not working

Comment: Are you sure you're using the production build of the React client-side script?

Comment: Yes I did And main.js minified and uglified @gcampbell